# .gitignore ignoring file with "production" in its name

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repo which has datasources.json. I added a new file datasources.production.json in the same repo. When I try to commit and push git is ignoring this file. I verified .gitignore file there is no such rule to ignore this file. I don't know if I am missing anything. Anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Is there a global `.gitignore` file in your home directory? Are there other `.gitignore` files in the repository besides the one in the root directory? Also, can you include the content of the `.gitignore` file(s) in the question (as well as the full path of the file from the repository root) so we can double-check your assessment?

Comment: go `git config --global -l` and look for `core.excludesfile`

Comment: @ChrisMartin - Yes, gitignore is present in the home directory which is the only gitignore file in the repo.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I verified core.excludesfile as well and I dont see any exclusion for *.production.* or anything like that which should skip this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To diagnose this, run "git status datasources.production.json". If it is untracked, run "git add datasources.production.json" and see if there is a message or error. Commit, and verify that the file is part of that commit. Finally, when you push, you can check the server's commit "git show --stat origin/master" and check whether the file is present.

The first part may reveal whether there is in fact a .gitignore. If it fails in the second step, there may be a server rule (pre-commit hook) preventing this file from being allowed.

Comment: git status datasources.production.json says "nothing to commit"

Comment: Okay, here's another idea. Rename the file. Does git status see it now? Does git say the original one was deleted? Or try copying the file several times and use similar names. Find out whether ".production" is causing the file to be ignored, or something else. Finally, have you ever set git to "assume unchanged"? (Probably not, but if so, you should run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>` to unset this.)

Comment: Unfortunately there was a gitignore ignoring this file inside a sub directory which contained this file and I didn't notice it :(